# Finding count in multiple tables

Tags: sql

I need to find the amount of times a customer appears in the Orders and Requests   tables respectively.  However this script is producing the same count value for both places where COUNT is used.  The value cannot possibly be the same so what am I doing wrong?

```
  SELECT   o.CustomerID, 
         COUNT(o.CustomerID) as OrdersPerCustomer,
         COUNT(r.CustomerID) as RequestsPerCustomer
  FROM Orders o
  INNER JOIN  [Customers] c on c.ID = o.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN  [Request] r on r.CustomerID = c.ID
  GROUP BY o.CustomerID
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Have you tried `COUNT(DISTINCT r.CustomerID)`?

Comment: DISTINCT just makes the counts 1 all the way down the line.   I expect the total number of times a customer ID appears in both tables.

Comment: and why do you need `join` on `Customers` table? I think you can skip it and `join` `Orders ` to `Request` simply

Comment: use cte's for each count and join together?

Comment: I join to customers because I'll need some data from there that's not relevant to the count.

Comment: `SELECT   o.CustomerID, 
         COUNT(o.CustomerID) as OrdersPerCustomer,
         COUNT(r.CustomerID) as RequestsPerCustomer
  FROM [Customers] c
  INNER JOIN Orders o  on c.ID = o.CustomerID
  OUTER JOIN  [Request] r on r.CustomerID = c.ID
  GROUP BY o.CustomerID` Have you tried this query?

Comment: Does the second join have to be an outer join?  There is something about the syntax that's causing problems.  The OUTER is the only difference between what you have and what I wrote.

Comment: a LEFT OUTER JOIN works syntax wise but it again produces 99% of the same values for both COUNTS.

Comment: Ya second join is OUTER JOIN. I mean FULL OUTER JOIN in mysql syntax. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying the number of order and request records. I.e. by joining the tables, you get for, say, 3 orders and 4 requests for a customer 12 result rows. As the IDs will never be null in a record, `COUNT(o.CustomerID)` and `COUNT(r.CustomerID)` are just `COUNT(*)` (12 in my example, and not 3 and 4 as you expected).

The easiest approach:

```
select
  customer_id,
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.customerid = c.id) as o_count,
  (select count(*) from request r where r.customerid = c.id) as r_count
from customers c;
```

The same with subqueries (derived tables) in the from clause:

```
select
  customer_id,
  coalesce(o.total, 0) as o_count,
  coalesce(r.total, 0) as r_count
from customers c
left join (select customerid, count(*) as total from orders group by customerid) o
  on o.customerid = c.id
left join (select customerid, count(*) as total from request group by customerid) r
  on r.customerid = c.id;
```

When aggregating from multiple tables, always aggregate first and join then.

Comment: That's great!  Is there a way I could exclude records where both counts are zero?

Comment: In the first query that's a bit difficult. You'd write an outer query `select * from (<query>) where o_count > 0 or r_count > 0`. In the second you would just add `where o.total > 0 or r.total > 0`.